# send data from list to sharepoint application page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

is there any way to connect a SharePoint application page to a list in the SharePoint to save data inside form (in application page) to the list in the SharePoint      i need to know it i can make connection code in the application page to connect to the list or if there is another way to do that

this is my code

```
    <asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<input type="text" id="txta"/> <input type="text" id="txtb" /> 
<textarea id="txtarea" cols="10" rows="2">Text area</textarea> 
<input type="submit" /> </form>
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"> Application Page </asp:Content>
```

i need to write a code to add the information in this form ,when user insert his information and click submit data sent to share point list

Answer (score 0):

First I would update your form inputs to be server controls so you can reference them easily from your code behind file. Then in your code behind you would use the following code:

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://Site_Name"))
{
    using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("/"))
    {
        SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["Tasks"];

        SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items.Add();
        oListItem["Title"] = txtArea.Text;
        oListItem.Update();
    }
}
```